# sybase stored procedure slow after deleting rows

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase, sqlanywhere

We deleted table rows in order to improve performance since we had a very large database. The database size reduced to 50% but the stored procedure became even more slower after the delete. It used to run within 3 minutes and now it is taking 3 hours. No changes made to procedure.

We ran the same procedure again in old database(before delete) and it worked fine. All other procedures run faster after the database size reduction. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please provide more details. Is the procedure using only one table? is it using more than one table, what does the procedure "do"? Have you tried rebuilding your indexes?

Comment: Bogdan, The procedure uses 4 different tables. I have not tried rebuilding indexes. I was wondering how to identify if indexes had been used previously in procedure.

Comment: @user2856752 - Hi, if you found my answer helpful, please be sure to upvote and accept the answer.  For more information on how to accept an answer, see the page here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Deleting rows in the database doesn't truly free up space on it's own.

Space usually isn't really freed up until you run a command that can reorganize the data stored in the table.  In SAP ASE the command `reorg` can be run with options such as `reclaim space`, `rebuild` and `forwarded rows` on the database.  Logically, it's a lot like defragmenting a hard drive, the data is reorganized to use less physical space.

In SQL Anywhere the command is [`REORGANIZE TABLE`](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/dbusage/obtaining-fragmentation-stats.html), or can be found on the **[Fragmentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/dbusage/obtaining-fragmentation-stats.html)** tab in Sybase Central.  This will also help with [index fragmentation](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/dbusage/detecting-index-frag.html).

The other thing that frequently needs to be done after large changes to the database is to update the table or index statistics.  The query optimizer builds the query plans based of the table statistics stored in system tables.  When large transactions, or a large number of small transactions happen, the statistics can lead the optimizer to make less optimal choices.

In SQL Anywhere this can be done using [Sybase Central](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/dbusage/addremovestats.html).

You may also want to check out the [Monitoring and improving database performance](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.0/dbusage/ug-part-monitor.html) section of the SQL Anywhere documentation.  It covers these procedures, and much more.

Comment: Thank you Michael,

The application uses SQL anywhere from sybase. The above solution still holds true? Yes, I am referring to the number of rows..

Comment: The same concepts apply, but the commands are a bit different.  I'll update my answer.